# How long does it take for an unplucked Pikmin to grow a flower?

Tags: pikmin

In Pikmin 1, if you wait long enough before plucking a Pikmin, the leaf on its head will grow into a flower which makes it move faster. How long do you need to wait before plucking a Pikmin before its leaf grows into a flower?

[image]
[Image from Pikipedia](https://www.pikminwiki.com/File:Pikmin_Stages_in_Pikmin.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

[Every few minutes](https://www.pikminwiki.com/Maturity) apparently it will evolve into the next stage:

> The most basic way for Pikmin to increase in level is to let them remain underground for some time without plucking them. As they stay underground, they extract nutrients from the soil,[2] which allows them to evolve from their current stage to the next one every few minutes.

If you feed them nectar in the bud of leaf stage, they will immediately flower.